# Rust private function throws error when trying to return tuple of values

Tags: rust, tuples, return, ownership, borrow

I have a function I am attempting to return a tuple of values from:

```rust
fn get_two_bytes(data: &[u8]) -> (Vec<(u8, u8)>, BTreeSet<(u8, u8)>) {
    let two_byte_vec = data
        .chunks(2)
        .map(|x| (x[0], x[1]))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let mut two_byte_set : BTreeSet<&(u8, u8)> = BTreeSet::new();
    for n in &two_byte_vec {
        two_byte_set.insert(n);
    }

    return (two_byte_vec, two_byte_set);
}
```

This error is generated:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:13:27
   |
13 |     return (two_byte_vec, two_byte_set);
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected tuple, found `&(u8, u8)`
   |
   = note: expected struct `BTreeSet<(u8, u8)>`
              found struct `BTreeSet<&(u8, u8)>`
```

I don't want to return `&two_byte_set` obviously - I want to transfer ownership out of the function. How do I get these two variables to return properly?

Comment: The error message here is misleading. It's talking about the type that BTreeMap holds. Which is &(u8, u8). Just deref n before inserting into the map and remove the type annotation from two_byte_set

Comment: @IvanC the error is not misleading, just truncated, thats why you should always read and provide the full error message, not just one line of it.

Comment: I've seen discussions by @ekuber about improving this exact error message on Mastodon, most people agree that the wording is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message here is misleading.

It's talking about the type that `BTreeMap` holds, which is `&(u8, u8)` rather than `(u8, u8)` you promise Int the function signature. Since `u8` is `Copy`, tuple `(u8, u8)` is also
`Copy`, which means you can just deref `n` before inserting into the map and remove the type annotation from `two_byte_set`.

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

fn get_two_bytes(data: &[u8]) -> (Vec<(u8, u8)>, BTreeSet<(u8, u8)>) {
    let two_byte_vec = data.chunks(2).map(|x| (x[0], x[1])).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let mut two_byte_set = BTreeSet::new();
    for &n in &two_byte_vec {
        two_byte_set.insert(n);
    }

    (two_byte_vec, two_byte_set);
}
```

Comment: I think it is useful to clarify that `&n` here isn't a borrow, it's a pattern that matches and dereferences a reference.

Comment: @IvanC, nice notice! I've used to write **two_byte_set.insert(*n)** in such contexts.

Comment: The pattern match and dereference of a reference of `n` (specifically at declaration time) was confusing to me. This worked! I also would prefer a different stracktrace error. Thanks to @IvanC for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Since you borrow the vector to iterate over in your `for` loop, the type of `n` in that loop is `&(u8, u8)`. Fortunately, tuples of `u8` can be cloned, so simply clone them into your set.

```
let mut two_byte_set : BTreeSet<(u8, u8)> = BTreeSet::new();
for n in &two_byte_vec {
    two_byte_set.insert(n.to_owned());
}
```